# Why doesn't blender grease pencil solid fill interpolate properly

Tags: rendering, keyframes, grease-pencil, interpolation

I'm kinda noob when it comes to grease pencil in blender, I'm trying to render wavy blocks to maybe use as sprites in a  game I'm creating, the strokes seem to get interpolated quite nicely but not the fills, I had to hand fill every interpolated stroke with solid fill to make a decent animation, when fills are interpolated, the painted shape in start keyframe just swirls around eerily and takes the end shape.. I'm very bothered
[image]
[image]

Comment: Would you please include some images in your post of the behavior?  Having a .blend is helpful for referencing in more complicated scenarios but when at all possible we like to work off images so that all information can be found in the post itself without downloading any files.

Comment: Ok I've made a video of what's happening probably it'll help
http://imgur.com/gallery/p3cn77E